# Two-Sided Bounds on Binomial Sum

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

I came across this partial sum which I cannot find reasonable bounds on; I feel this must be known in the literature, but I do not know where to look.  Here is the problem:

Let $s\in (0,1)$ and consider the binomial sum
$$
\boldsymbol{(*)}\qquad \sum_{k=1}^N\, \binom{N}{k}\, \frac1{k^s}
$$
are there any known good upper and lower bounds on $\boldsymbol{(*)}$?

Comment: first reaction: maybe use generating functions?

Comment: Ya but this thing is not integrable at the state $X=0$ where $X\sim Bin(N,k)$.

Comment: The dominant terms come from $k\approx N/2$. This is close to $2^N/(N/2)^s$.

Comment: The generating function for $(\star)$ is $$\mathrm{Li}_s\big(\frac{x}{1-x}\big)\frac1{1-x}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}$We have to lower- and upper-bound
\begin{equation*}
    \Si_N:=\sum_{k=1}^N\,\binom Nk\, \frac1{k^s}. 
\end{equation*}

Note that
\begin{equation*}
    \Si_N=2^N EX^{-s}\,1(X\ge1), \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
where $X$ is a random variable with the binomial distribution with parameters $N,1/2$.

By Jensen's inequality applied to the convex function $[1,\infty)\ni x\mapsto x^{-s}$,
\begin{equation*}
    EX^{-s}\,1(X\ge1)=P(X\ge1)\,E(X^{-s}|X\ge1) \\ 
    \ge P(X\ge1)\,(E(X|X\ge1))^{-s}. \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
Also,
\begin{equation*}
    E(X|X\ge1)=\dfrac{EX\,1(X\ge1)}{P(X\ge1)}=\dfrac{EX}{P(X\ge1)}=\dfrac{N/2}{P(X\ge1)} \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
and $P(X\ge1)=1-2^{-N}$. So, by \eqref{10}, \eqref{20}, and \eqref{30}, we get a lower bound on $\Si_N$:
\begin{equation*}
    \Si_N\ge L_N:=M_N\,(1-2^{-N})^{1+s}, \tag{33}\label{33}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    M_N:=\frac{2^N}{(N/2)^s}. \tag{35}\label{35}
\end{equation*}

To get an upper bound on $\Si_N$, write
\begin{equation*}
    EX^{-s}\,1(X\ge1)=E_1+E_2, \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    E_1:=EX^{-s}\,1(X\ge\tfrac N2\,(1-h)),\quad \\ E_2:=EX^{-s}\,1(1\le X<\tfrac N2\,(1-h)), 
\end{equation*}
and $h\in(0,1-2/N]$. Next,
\begin{equation*}
    E_1\le(\tfrac N2\,(1-h))^{-s}. \tag{50}\label{50}
\end{equation*}
By Hoeffding's inequality,
\begin{equation*}
    E_2\le P(1\le X<\tfrac N2\,(1-h)) \\ 
\le \exp(-\tfrac2N\,(\tfrac{Nh}2)^2)=e^{-h^2 N/2}=N^{-c^2/2} \tag{60}\label{60}
\end{equation*}
if $h=c\sqrt{\frac{\ln N}N}\in(0,1-2/N]$. So, in view of \eqref{10}, \eqref{40}, \eqref{50}, \eqref{35}, and \eqref{60}, we get an upper bound on $\Si_N$:
\begin{equation*}
    \Si_N\le U_N:=M_N\,\Big[\Big(1-c\sqrt{\frac{\ln N}N}\,\Big)^{-s}
    +2^{-s}N^{s-c^2/2}\Big]. 
    \tag{70}\label{70}
\end{equation*}

Fixing now any real $c>\sqrt{2s}$, letting $N\to\infty$, and looking at \eqref{33} and \eqref{70}, we see that $L_N\sim M_N\sim U_N$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \Si_N\sim L_N\sim U_N\sim M_N=\frac{2^N}{(N/2)^s}. 
\end{equation*}
Thus, our lower and upper bounds $L_N$ and $U_N$ on $\Si_N$ are asymptotically exact for large $N$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more precise value you can expand $k^{-s}$ around $k=N/2$ and sum term by term.  I get
$$\frac{2^N}{(N/2)^s}\Bigl(1 + \frac{s(1+s)}{2N} +
\frac{s(1+s)(2+s)(3+s)}{8N^2} + O(N^{-3})\Bigr).$$

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but this expansion, I mean the $O(\cdot)$ term, needs to be justified -- which apparently can be done by using Hoeffding's inequality, as in my answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis  Yes of course you are right. I wasn't intending to present a rigorous proof, though an approach like yours will certainly provide one.  Incidentally, it seems like all the terms of the expansion are positive, but that's just an empirical observation. Can you prove $2^N/(N/2)^s$ is a lower bound?

Comment: No, actually $2^N/(N/2)^s$ is not a lower bound when $s$ is very close to 0. The limit as $s\to 0$ is  $2^N/(N/2)^s-1$. So  I modify my conjecture to say that $2^N/(N/2)^s-1$ is a lower bound and is sharp.

Comment: Maybe, the latter expression is a lower bound?